# Count time with PHP and DateTime, can not get the right time with "diff" and "add"

Tags: php, datetime, time, addition, subtraction

Trying to calculate time for tracking some tasks. I need to consider some breaks that I first check with some IF statements and later i need to subtract all breaks from the total time before posing the time to my database. The start and finish tome comes from a HTML form with the input type "time" and the breaks as hardcoded in the code as you can se below. Are they considered to be strings?

I want to make this happen. 
("Finish time" - "Start time" - "all breaks" =  "Totalt time"). But somehow I cant make this work..

Here is my code:

```
//Check for breaks
if ($time_start <= "10:00:00" and $time_finish >= "10:10:00"){
  $halftime_morning = "00:10:00";
} else $halftime_morning = "";

if ($time_start <= "11:20:00" and $time_finish >= "11:50:00"){
  $lunch = "00:30:00";
} else $lunch = "";
if ($time_start <= "15:00:00" and $time_finish >= "15:10:00"){
  $halftime_afternoon = "00:10:00";
} else $halftime_afternoon = "";

if ($time_start <= "17:00:00" and $time_finish >= "17:30:00"){
  $dinner = "00:30:00";
} else $dinner = "";

//Calculates the total working hours
$total_working_time = new DateTime($time_finish);
$total_working_time->diff(new DateTime($time_start));
echo "Working time :" . $total_working_time->format("H:i:s") . "\n";


$halftime = new DateTime($halftime_morning);
$halftime->add(new DateInterval($halftime_afternoon));
//echo "Working time" . $halftime->format('H:i:s') . "\n";

$food = new DateTime($lunch);
$food->add(new DateInterval($dinner));
//echo "Food" . $food->format("H:i:s") . "\n";

$break = new DateTime($food);
$break->add(new DateInterval($halftime));
//echo "Break"  .$break->format("H:i:s") . "\n";

$total_working_time = new DateTime($working_time);
$total_working_time->diff(new DateTime($break));
//$total_working_time = "";
```

Also tried to add new DateTime() on the breaks like this:

```
$dinner = new DateTime("00:30:00");
```

Another solution I've tried:

```
$break = (strtotime($halftime_morning) + strtotime($lunch) + strtotime($halftime_afternoon) + strtotime($dinner));
echo date('H:i:s', $break );
```

Example from Stack Overflow also tried

```
$origin   = '00:00:00';
$newTotal = '00:45:00';
$oldTotal = '00:16:00';

$added = strtotime($newTotal) + (strtotime($oldTotal) - strtotime($origin));
echo date('H:i:s', $added )
```

This is one of my errors from the first code snippet:

```
Working time :21:30:00 Catchable fatal error: 
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in filename.php on line 72
```

Line 72 is my code to insert data in SQL. I have got tons or errors in my code trying to manipulate the time before.

I really don't understand how to solve this. As I understand part of my problem is that I'm trying to match a string with a time. Is the data from my form (input type (time) considered to be a string or a time? Does it matter if I use "" or "00:00:00" for my breaks?

For a while I got "diff" to work with DateTime but never "add". Currently it does not even subtract the start time from the finish time..

Any suggestions?

Edit: I think i need to clarify. My time is is never counted correct. For my total time the starting time never gets subtracted and fot the rest of the breaks I get errors referring me to mix strings and time.

New example:
The following code somehow outputs "2:20" when I use seconds instead of 1:20 that would be correct..

```
//Check for breaks
if ($time_start <= "10:00:00" and $time_finish >= "10:10:00"){
  $halftime_morning = (10*60);//"00:10:00";
} else $halftime_morning = 0;

if ($time_start <= "11:20:00" and $time_finish >= "11:50:00"){
 $lunch = (30*60);//""00:30:00";
} else $lunch = 0;
if ($time_start <= "15:00:00" and $time_finish >= "15:10:00"){
 $halftime_afternoon = (10*60);//"00:10:00";
} else $halftime_afternoon = 0;

if ($time_start <= "17:00:00" and $time_finish >= "17:30:00"){
 $dinner = (30*60);//"00:30:00";
   } else $dinner = 0;

   $break = 0;
$break = ($halftime_morning + $lunch + $halftime_afternoon + $dinner);
echo date('H:i:s', $break );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert all your strings to timestamps. It's easier to work with them.

I tried this, and it should be your expected output.

```
$time_start = strtotime("10:00:00")%(60*60*24); //10:00 in seconds 
$time_end = strtotime("17:30:00")%(60*60*24); //17:30 in seconds

$halftime_morning = 10*60; // 10 minutes - 600 seconds
$lunch = 30*60; //30 minutes - 1800 seconds
$halftime_afternoon = 10*60; //10 minutes - 600 seconds
$dinner = 30*60; //30 minutes - 1800 seconds

$totalBreak = $halftime_morning + $lunch + $halftime_afternoon + $dinner;

echo gmdate('H:i:s', $totalBreak );
```

When you're checking, that the time is between the specific time for dinner/lunch etc. you will also have to convert this values to timestamps